# Copy required dlls with CMake/MSBuild

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cmake, msbuild, shared-libraries

### Problem

I use Visual Studio 12 (2013) with MSBuild 12.0.40629.0. 
I have two projects, `A` and `B`. `A` depends on the shared library built by project `B`.
At the moment I use something like the following `cmake` code to copy my required shared libraries (dlls):

```
project(A)

add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/B.dll
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
```

This generally works, but if I modify code of project `B` without modifying project `A`, the post build command of project `A` isn't called (I didn't modify the project) and I am stuck with a old shared library. At the moment I add a space character and remove it to force build project `A`/run post build.

### Stupid solution

I could copy the shared library with a post build command in project `B` to project `A`, but that means I have two locations, where dlls are copied.

### More elegant solution

While writing this I came to another better solution. Copying shared library in post build of `B` to project `A` is sufficient, but makes the project structure more intertwined.

### Question

How do I make CMake or MSBuild copy dlls in a more elegant way, so this edge case is solved.

Comment: Can't recall at all in CMake, but if at the msbuild/vcxproj/sln level project `A` depends on `B`, then rebuilding B should cause project A to build, which will include any post build or "Custom Build Tool" items with relevant inputs/dependencies. I also haven't used 2013 for years, but I don't recall any bugs with this.

Comment: @Fire Lancer it should, but somehow it doesn't. Linker and project dependencies are set. In my case it is linked, but in general it could be a module/plugin that is loaded at runtime. I still don't understand how msbuild decides if a project needs to be built. After building, Visual Studio says one successful and the other projects are up-to-date. It did build only the dependency and of course I have project `A` as startproject and selected in project explorer. If I build again it says all are up-to-date.

Comment: You can set target dependencies in `CMake`. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/add_dependencies.html

Comment: @drescherjm I did, this creates dependencies in MSBuild/Visual Studio, but that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Or you can simply stop using the old dinosaur cmake.

Comment: cmake is the standard build tool and this is also a msbuild issue so idk